# Macbook Pro 2019 Core i9 can fry an egg

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro 2019 with Core i9-9980HK.

It's a good machine but something that bothers me is , the fan is always on and screaming.

I tried a lot of things to improve it :

- Opened its cover and cleaned the dust of the fans
- Monitored processes to see if there is something on high CPU usage, but apparently it's normal

I installed an app to monitore cpu temperature and usually it keeps an average of 70-80 celsius, with eventual peaks of 95 / 100 but never below 65.

But anyway, when i put my fingers on the machine above the keyboard, it's always hot, sometimes really hot.

Can this be considered normal ?

I know Intel is energy hungry and i know the newer Macs with Apple Silicon are better but so far i need an Intel machine to virtualize Windows and need to stick with this for a couple of years.

Comment: Temperatures like that I'd have at least expected kernel_task to be running amok trying to make it cool itself. Activity Monitor > View > All Processes. Do you run external display[s]? Have you tried plugging the power into the opposite side of the Mac?

Comment: If the processor part number ends with a K (e.g. i9-13900K or KF) then that processor TDP may be unlocked and the processor could run as hot as is possible while still being within thermal budgets. Depending on your cooling that could easily mean hitting 90+ Celsius. Of course saying that 100C is "okay" for your CPU doesn't explain why your system is *always* running hard, because it should not be doing that permanently. Most modern systems with good cooling should quickly end up idling and the CPU should drop below 50c.

Comment: Do you have the Dropbox or Google Drive software (or similar web file/storage service) installed, by any chance? I found those two packages made my Intel-based MBP's fans run all the time, but it was harder to diagnose since they mostly consist of daemons, not apps. I uninstalled those and decided it was okay if I had to use a web browser to get to Dropbox and Google Drive files.

Comment: @Mokubai Mine it's a Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK, so it has a K on the end.

Comment: @Tetsujin Recently i changed the power from left port to right port ; doesn't seem to make difference

Comment: @Spiff No dropbox here, only iCloud